# MIME types error when using URL rewriting on Springboot server and Angular app

Tags: angular, spring-boot, url-rewriting, caddy, caddyfile

I am working on a SpringBoot application with 2 Angular app frontend that are located as such :
Springboot app : `src -> main -> java`
Angular app 1 (fo) : `src -> main -> resources -> public -> fo`
Angular app 2 (bo) : `src -> main -> resources -> public -> bo`

*NOTE : In the root folder of the angular apps some files like `index.html` and `runtime-es[...].js` can be found (among others)*

So I created a `Controller` class for my Springboot app like this :

```java
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/fo")
  public String index() {
      return "/fo/index.html";
  }

  @GetMapping("/bo")
  public String admin() {
      return "/bo/index.html";
  }
}
```

As well as a `Configuration` class :

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {MainApplicationImpl.class})
@EnableWebSecurity
public class PresentationConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
  }

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/fo/**")
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/public/fo/")
      .resourceChain(true)
      .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
        @Override
        protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
          Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);

          return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable() ? requestedResource
            : new ClassPathResource("/public/fo/index.html");
        }
      });

    registry.addResourceHandler("/bo/**")
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/public/bo/")
      .resourceChain(true)
      .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
        @Override
        protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
          Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);

          return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable() ? requestedResource
            : new ClassPathResource("/public/bo/index.html");
        }
      });
  }
```

The idea is that `fo` should be available on the internet, for example on `http://www.fo.com/`, and `bo` only available on the internal network of my client, let's say `http://client.bo.internal/`.

To simulate that, I setted up some sort of "reverse_proxy" that rewrites the URL using docker and Caddy, here is the example for url rewriting of `bo`:

Caddyfile

```
localhost:80 {
    route /* {
        rewrite /* /bo/*
        reverse_proxy http://host.docker.internal:8081
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    image: caddy
    #command
    volumes:
      - ./Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
    ports:
      - '8082:80'
```

That way, when I type `http://localhost:8082` on a web browser, it calls my Springboot app as such : `http://localhost:8081/bo`.
This *kinda* works since I am getting the index.html file showing on the page but every links to js files and css files are getting an error showing

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Here are some screenshot of what I can see in the developments tools of the browser :

HTML content of `http://localhost:8082` :
[image: HTML content]

Errors in console :
[image: Errors in console]

Network tab :
[image: Network tab]

Here's some funny business, every files seems to have the content of `index.html`:
[image: Content of some .js file]

Since the problem seems to come from MIME types, how can I specify that the .js files called from a .html files are not `text/html` but `application/javascript` (if it is really my problem) ?

From what I've found on the internet about this error, it can be fixed by rewriting the `<base href="/" />` tag. But I *do not* want to do this because it will mean that the URL will have to be `http://localhost/fo/`.

Hope you can help me, thanks for reading !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to fix this, the error showed because of the configuration of my CaddyFile. Using the `url replace` instead of `rewrite`.

New CaddyFile :

```
localhost:80 {
    route /* {
        uri replace / /bo/ 1
        reverse_proxy http://host.docker.internal:8081
    }
}
```

That will replace the first occurence of `/` to `/bo/`, so I call `http://localhost:8082/` and get  `http://localhost:8081/bo/`. You would expect the `rewriting` syntax to do exactly this but apparently not.